# laravel 5 eloquent left join

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have next DB query:

```
Database::select(['*',
     \DB::raw('count(notes.id) as count')
     ])->leftjoin('notes','post.id','=','notes.post_id')
    ->groupBy('post.id');
```

1.How to do this use Eloquent

My relationship

```
//Post model
 public function notes(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Note','post_id');
    }
//Note model
 public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Database');
    }
```

2.How get the best list posts and list notes.Example on site:
 
id post|title post|count notes|
   ---notes 1
   ..........
**UPDATE**

```
 CREATE TABLE `posts` (
        `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        `text` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
         `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
         PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )

CREATE TABLE `notes` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `note` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `post_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see your update about your case, i think you only need standart eloquent relationship in your Models

1. put this relation in `App\Post.php`

   ```
   public function notes(){
      return $this->hasMany('App\Note','post_id');
   }
   ```
2. If you want to get your data like you describe above you can use this code

   Controller

   ```
   $view = view('your-view-file');
   $view->posts = App\Post::all();
   return $view;
   ```

   View

   ```
   @foreach($posts as $post)
   <tr>
       <td>{{ $post->id }}</td>
       <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
       <td>{{ $post->notes->count() }}</td>
   </tr>
   @endforeach
   ```

you can use `count()` to sum number of row you got from database

Comment: This model return null result.

Comment: can you add more information about your code and database ?

Comment: Hi @MarcoRoys i'm already update my answer, and tried it myself with your database setup and it's working correctly